# How to retain object attributes when re-ordering with dragula?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dragula

The below code is for a simple component that fetches a list of colors from an API endpoint. A user can then drag colors between a left container and a right container. In the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, the component pushes all of the colors from the API into the component's state as objects with the following attributes:

```
{ id, name, index }
```

These colors are correctly placed into the left container when the state updates. The right container remains empty.

In the `render` method, if I add a logger to spit out the `availableColors` array, each object has a name, ID, and index. As it should be. E.g:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'red', index: 0 }
```

But when I drag and drop colors from the left container into the right container and the dragula on drop callback is executed, I can only access the `innerHTML` of each color added to the right container. This means I lose out on the object's properties like the ID it got from the API.

In other words, where I'm pushing into `newColorList`, `color.id` is blank. I think my issue is that I shouldn't be fetching the dropped elements using:

```
const targetContainer = document.querySelector('#right');
const selectedColorItems = targetContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

How should I fix this code?

```
class DragApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      availableColors: [],
      selectedColors: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/color-list.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        var availableColors = [];

        json.forEach(function(color, index) {
          availableColors.push({ index, name: color.name, id: color.id })
        });

        this.setState({ availableColors });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(ex) {
        // handle failure
      });

    dragula([document.querySelector('#left'), document.querySelector('#right')])
      .on('drop', function(el, _) {
          const newColorList = [];
          const targetContainer = document.querySelector('#right');
          const selectedColorItems = targetContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");

          Array.from(selectedColorItems).forEach(function(color) {
            // getIndexInParent returns index of element
            const index = getIndexInParent(color);
            newColorList.push({ index, name: color.innerHTML, id: color.id })
          })

          this.setState({ selectedColors: newColorList });
      }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    const colorsList = this.state.availableColors;
    const colors = colorsList.map((color) =>
      <li key={ color.id }>
        { color.name }
      </li>
    );

    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <ul id="left" className="container">
          { colors }
        </ul>

        <ul id="right" className="container"></ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I improved my reply, I hope it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the data attributes to store your colors info and retrieve them when you drop the li:

```
class DragApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            availableColors: [],
            selectedColors: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/color-list.json')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(function(json) {
                var availableColors = [];

                json.forEach(function(color, index) {
                    availableColors.push({
                        index,
                        name: color.name,
                        id: color.id
                    })
                });

                this.setState({
                    availableColors
                });
            }.bind(this))
            .catch(function(ex) {
                // handle failure
            });

        dragula([document.getElementById('#left'), document.getElementById('#right')])
            .on('drop', function(el, _) {
                const targetContainer = document.querySelector('#right');
                const selectedColorItems = targetContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");
                newColorList = Array.from(selectedColorItems).map(function(color) {
                    return {
                        index: color.dataset.index,
                        id: color.dataset.id,
                        name: color.text
                    };
                });
                this.setState({
                    selectedColors: newColorList
                });
            }.bind(this));
    }

    render() {
        const colorsList = this.state.availableColors;
        const colors = colorsList.map((color) =>
            <li key = { color.id } data-id="{ color.id }" data-index="{ color.index }">
                { color.name }
            </li>
        );

        return (
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <ul id="left" className="container">
                    { colors }
                </ul>

                <ul id="right" className="container"> </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the `getIndexInParent` idea, you should use `array.find()`

```
var getIndexInParent = function getIndexInParent(id) {
    return this.state.availableColors.find(function(color) {
        return color.id == id;
    });
};
```